# Integrating latexmk and TikZ external mode=list and make

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling, tikz-external, latexmk

I've been looking into using `latexmk` to create my documents because it automatically handles how many passes the document needs to be fully processed etc. So, for example, a simple run of `latexmk -pdf file.tex` will run `pdflatex` and `bibtex` as many times as necessary to resolve all references.

I was wondering whether it's possible to not lose the ability to do so when using the `TikZ`/`external` library in the `list and make` mode. If `list and make` is used, the `TikZ`/`external` makefile is generated, but it is not automatically called by `latexmk`. You can run the makefile manually and, of course, that will generate the graphic files, but the problem is that, as far as `latexmk` is concerned, the `.tex` files remain unchanged, so running `latexmk` once more does not insert the newly-generated graphics into the document.

So, given `file.tex` that uses `TikZ`/`external` in the `list and make` mode, this is what happens:

- `latexmk -pdf file.tex` generates the pdf and inserts placeholders for the not-yet-generated graphics.
- `make -f file.makefile` processes and generates the pdf files for the graphics.
- `latexmk -pdf file.tex` does nothing because the source files have not changed.

I assume there's a way to force the generation of the pdf in the second `latexmk` pass, but that would mean that this would happen even if the source files remained unchanged.

I was wondering whether there was a way to use `latexmk` to handle all of this "automagicaly"? That would be great!

Here's a MWE to get everyone started:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\begin{filecontents}{plot.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \input{plot.tikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't latexmk automagic, but it avoids recompiling if the source .tex file hasn't changed:

```
latexmk -pdf file.tex
make -n -f file.makefile > /dev/null | grep pdflatex > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  make -f file.makefile
  latexmk -g -pdf file.tex
fi
```

If the auto-generated makefile isn't actually going to compile any figures, the string "pdflatex" won't appear in the output of the dry-run; otherwise, the figures are compiled and latexmk is forced to do at least one more compilation.

---

Alternatively, here is a latexmkrc file that works most of the time: it runs the external makefile once per latexmk invocation, after the first time pdflatex is called.

If you are compiling the document from scratch, latexmk will most likely run pdflatex multiple times, and so the figures will be included after the first run.  If you are not building from scratch, then there is a good chance that latexmk will recognize that the external figures are being included, see that they have been updated by the external makefile, and then decide to run pdflatex again because of the changing dependencies.

Warning: this is the first time I've written perl:

```
our %externalflag = ();

$pdflatex = 'internal mypdflatex %O %S %B';

sub mypdflatex {
  our %externalflag;
  my $n = scalar(@_);
  my @args = @_[0 .. $n - 2];
  my $base = $_[$n - 1];

  system 'pdflatex', @args;
  if ($? != 0) {
    return $?
  }
  if ( !defined $externalflag->{$base} ) {
    $externalflag->{$base} = 1;
    system ("$make -j8 -f $base.makefile");
  }
  return $?;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of using this sort of sorcery to solve this. It seems like this method does not sacrifice any functionality provided by the `list and make` mode. Thanks a lot! I won't mark this as accepted just yet in case a more portable, `LaTeX`-y, `latexmk`-y answer is provided.

Comment: I very much like the first solution you present. I have to use a slightly modified version where I leave out the first `> /dev/null`

Comment: For reference only, [John Collins](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/8495) improved and corrected (his words) this solution in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444224/142706).

Answer (score 5):

This is not a straight forward answer to your question, but another way of achieving your overall goal: Outsourcing TikZ-pictures and rebuilding them only if they have changed.

This can be done using the [`standalone` class](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/standalone/standalone.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}

\begin{filecontents}{plot.tex}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \includestandalone{plot}
\end{document}
```

This could fit your needs quite well, as you are already putting your TikZ-pictures in separate files *and* everything works "automagically" with `latexmk`. Caveat: The files have to have the extension `.tex` instead of `.tikz` and you have to add a few more lines of code.

Comment: This is a good alternative, but it sacrifices some of the functionality offered by the `list and make` mode unfortunately. For example, the ability to automatically re-generate the plot when a data file changes. I'm also not sure whether the `standalone` method can resolve a reference to, for example, a `pgfplots` legend (which I think requires two passes).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, but here's a hack I figured out a couple of days after first looking up this question here.

For context, I'm using `latexmk -pvc` (i.e. in "continuous preview" mode), with okular as pdf viewer and kate as text editor; shouldn't matter though.

---

`latexmkrc`:

```perl
$analyze_input_log_always=1;
$default_files=("file.tex");
$make="make -k -j 6"; # `-k`: keep trying on errors; -j 6: six parallel jobs
$use_make_for_missing_files=1; # probably only this is needed
$pdf_mode=4; # use lualatex
set_tex_cmds('--shell-escape --synctex=1 %O %S'); # generate source mapping
```

I don't know enough about latex etc to tell which parts are actually needed; maybe `$use_make_for_missing_files=1` is sufficient.

Somewhere in the latexmk docs theres the hint to use `\typeout{(filename)}` to declare a dependency, however some digging through the code reveals that this is discarded if that file doesn't already exist. However, if we make it sound scarier, it'll stay:

Tikz creates a `file.makefile` with a dummy target `allimages`. However, if the error message specifies no extension, latexmk will try a couple of them, but not to actually build just the plain name. Thus, we use this fake error message:

```latex
\typeout{}
\typeout{No file "allimages.pdf".}
\typeout{}
```

And create a new `makefile` to redirect it to the target generated by tikz:
`makefile`

```makefile
-include file.makefile
allimages.pdf: allimages
```

(Make sure that there's no `allimages.tex` or `allimages.pdf`)

---

caveats:

- latex first-timer here, so use at your own risk.
- I couldn't get this to work with a custom `out_dir`. `\tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/}` is fine though.
- latexmk will list the fake error message in its summary, even if everything went fine.
- I recommend setting a `\tikzfigurename` so that adding a new image in the beginning doesn't break everything,
- `\tikzfiguredependsonfile` needs to go *after* `\tikzfigurename`, but before `\begin{tikzpicture}`
- I encountered some situations where I broke some pre-existing images and latexmk decided to try `make`ing every individual image after the `allimages` target already failed. If it takes a long time before the error happens, this can be quite annoying.
- it can be quite hard to see whether all images compiled correctly, as any make output will be buried by the subsequent latex run. Try looking whether for every *.log there also is a *.pdf.

---

bonus: using the separate makefile, you can even define your own (implicit) recipes for data preprocessing. Trigger these via `\tikzpicturedependsonfile`.