# Parallel compiling of *slides* with beamer?

Tags: beamer, compiling, parallel

I understand that LaTeX cannot parallel process a whole document because of the layout algorithm which is intrinsiquely linear.

However, in my understanding, the overlay specifications of successive `slides` within each `frame` in a `beamer` class are just expanded into repeated, successive pages in a .pdf.

Is the compiling of various `slides` in one `frame` a `beamer` document parallelizable? If yes, how to enjoy it?

---

For instance, if I have to insert:

```
\begin{frame}
    \only<3-> {heavy stuff} % e.g. graphics, loads of tikz, video, etc..
    \foreach \i in {4,...,23} {
         \only<\i->{light stuff \i}
    }
\end{frame}
```

then the `heavy stuff` operation will be performed twice if the frame lasts on 5 slides, and 20 times linearly if the frame lasts on 23 slides.. so it will take forever to compile.. is this avoidable?

Comment: I would put the `{heavy stuff}` in a [savebox](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Boxes#savebox) and the copy it in the slide.

Comment: This sounds cool and should speed up compilation time indeed, cheers :) Any ideas about parallel processing of slides within frames?

Comment: If the heavy stuff can be externalized (TikZ or other graphics, for example), then the answers at [Integrating latexmk and TikZ external mode=list and make](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145501) could be helpful.

Comment: @MikeRenfro hmm, I've never heard of this before, and it sounds interesting.. I'll look into this :)

Comment: @lago-lito Did the externalisation solve your problem?

Comment: @samcarter Sadly, learning `external` and adapting my whole document to it has not been possible before I had to compile a definitive version. And I won't get back to it before I am done with my current job which will now concerns python matters (see you on SO! ;). So let the suspense stay on about [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302621) :) In my opinion, regardless of whether or not [`external` will help me compile faster](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145501), fudamental questionning about *LaTeX parallelism* opportunities for slides within beamer frames is still open.

Comment: The answer to the parallelism question has to be: no.  The content of a given overlay can depend on the compliation of the previous ones: e.g. `\def\foo{foo}` and then in the frame foreach loop `\only<\i->{\foo\xdef\foo{baz\foo}}`