# incremental compiling with multi-core-cpu on Sharelatex: files in cache are not found in next run of pdflatex

Tags: tikz-external, latexmk, sharelatex

I have many complex plots generated with `tikz`. 
There is a great method to incremental compile with multi-core-cpu   described in [Integrating latexmk and TikZ external mode=list and make](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145501/integrating-latexmk-and-tikz-external-mode-list-and-make)

### Automated work flow:

1. automatically generate individual tasks for each tikz-picture in a makefile (`\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]`)
2. compile tikz-pictures simultaneously  using 8-core cpu !!! (`make -j8 -f %B.makefile`)
3. automatically insert tikz-pictures as pdf-files in second run of pdflatex (`\usetikzlibrary{external}`)

Here is a simplified MWE that should work on our local machine.

Run with `latexmk  -pdf   main.tex`

```
%%% file named main.tex %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

%%%  please create file latexmkrc manually %%%
% \begin{filecontents}{latexmkrc} 
% $pdflatex='pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=batchmode %O %S;  make -f %B.makefile; pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=batchmode %O %S';
% \end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \tikzsetnextfilename{myPlot}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

### Observation in [Sharelatex](http://www.sharelatex.com)

I want to get the example working on Sharelatex on my own server. For testing, you can create a free account at [Sharelatex](http://www.sharelatex.com).

1. The makefile is generated by `tikz-external` as expected.
2. The `make`-command works as expected. The file **myPlot.pdf is generated** and can be found in cache beside the log-files.
3. In the second run of pdflatex, the **myPlot.pdf is NOT inserted** in the main-file.

### Problem

In the second run of pdflatex, it looks like **myPlot.pdf does not exist**. The warning is:

```
Package `tikz` Warning: Some images are not up-to-date and need to be generated.
```

And actually: if I download myPlot.pdf and upload it again so that it is a regular part of the project and not only a cached file, **everything works fine**!

### Question

**How can I tell sharelatex to see the cached files in the second run of pdflatex?**

I run the [community edition of Sharelatex](https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) in docker on my own server, so I have access to everything you might suggest.

Looking forward to Sunday -- has the easter bunny hid **any options, flags, ... in any config-file** deep inside the sharelatex-code that could help me? Maybe have to give access privileges to any processes?

*I would be really happy if you could help me. Furthermore, the solution could result in a great feature to other users for quite fast compiling on a fast multi-core server?!*

Comment: If you would like to test on your own server, do not forget to activate -shell-escape in /var/www/sharelatex/clsi/app/js/LatexRunner.js with respect to https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image/issues/45

Comment: What is produced beside the `.pdf`, which is probably not the most interesting file here. Which method is externalisation using to decide whether files require updating?