# Beamer, overlay and standalone

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, standalone

## Short version

Is it possible to use `standalone` to produce externally my figures with overlays and include them directly in my main document ?

## More details

Using the answers of the question [Beamer overlays, tikz external and custom file name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119428/beamer-overlays-tikz-external-and-custom-file-name) and [Integrating latexmk and TikZ external mode=list and make](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145501/integrating-latexmk-and-tikz-external-mode-list-and-make) I have been able to outsource my Tikz pictures while using overlay.

More precisely, I have the following `tex` files

```
% tikz/fig.tex

\begin{tikzpicture}[transform canvas={scale=0.5}]

    \node[visible on=<1->]  at (0,0) {Overlay 1};
    
    \node[visible on=<2>]  at (2,0) {Overlay 2};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

```
% main.tex

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make,prefix=tikz/]
\tikzset{
  invisible/.style={opacity=0},
  visible on/.style={alt={#1{}{invisible}}},
  alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
    \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
  },
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@slideinframe}
\tikzset{
  beamer externalizing/.style={%
    execute at end picture={%
      \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \ifbeamer@anotherslide
        \pgfexternalstorecommand{\string\global\string\beamer@anotherslidetrue}%
        \fi
      }{}%
    }%
  },
  external/optimize=false
}
\let\orig@tikzsetnextfilename=\tikzsetnextfilename
\renewcommand\tikzsetnextfilename[1]{\orig@tikzsetnextfilename{#1-\overlaynumber}}
\makeatother

\tikzset{every picture/.style={beamer externalizing}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
    \begin{figure}
        \only<1>{\tikzsetnextfilename{fig}}
        \only<2>{\tikzsetnextfilename{fig}}
        \input{tikz/fig.tikz}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then, I can use `latexmk` with the following `.latexmkrc`

```
our %externalflag = ();

$lualatex = 'internal mylualatex %O %S %B';

sub mylualatex {
  print "Hello world\n";
  our %externalflag;
  my $n = scalar(@_);
  my @args = @_[0 .. $n - 2];
  my $base = $_[$n - 1];

  system 'lualatex', @args;
  if ($? != 0) {
    return $?
  }
  if ( !defined $externalflag->{$base} ) {
    $externalflag->{$base} = 1;
    system ("$make -j8 -f $base.makefile");
  }
  return $?;
}
```

and it will produce all the figures (in my example two because I have two overlays) in parallel using `make`. The only issue now is that I would like to use `standalone` to be able to work directly on my picture and not recompiling the whole document each time.

I saw in the doc of `standalone` that it should be possible to generate frames with `standaloneframe`, but it is not really what I want since I want only pictures, and I did not succeed in including the resulting frame in my main document using `\includestandalone` anyway.

Comment: The issue then is can I produce automatically all the pdf I need using standalone with overlay ?

Comment: Ah, you are using the beamer version of tikz.  Note that each overlay is a separate image/page, whereas standalone typically generates only one image/page.

Comment: Exactly, so I wonder if there is a way to get pass this. For example, I know that you can produce a frame for each overlay version of the your page using standaloneframe (but I did not succeed in outsourcing this). Or may be there is some trick to produce several pdf and include them like I did with `external` and `Tikz`

Comment: Does it help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168705/1952

Comment: It is a nice workaround to produce several frames, good to know thanks ! But my main question is more about pictures, rather than frames.

Comment: @PierreMarchand Do you need 1 pdf file per `tikzpicture` ?

Comment: Maybe this post can help. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542668/break-a-diagram-in-multiple-independent-subdiagrams