# Break a diagram in multiple independent subdiagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

**Problematic**

At the end (of a class), this is the full graph I want to display.

[image: tikz]

But during the class, i'll present things step by step with **only nodes and arrows** in the "case #" area (and like an epiphany at the end, the different blocks are all connected).
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My problem**

On case 1 for instance.
First, I want to display only nodes and arrows strictly in the red area (not the arrows leading to other nodes, nor these other nodes outside the area).  But if I do a simple `\ifBlock1true`, I, of course, get in trouble with the arrows coming from 3-2 and 4-3.

For each case with `\newif` I'll get trouble with arrow i'll finally need to display in the full graph.

**Edit 1**

As you can see, @Schrodingerscat's great answer recreated the equivalent to `visible on` outside `beamer`.

As discussed in comments, inserting these graphs block by block as a single graph in an `article` or `book` will leave white space, white shadow of the nodes not yet displayed. (solution 1) .I was willing to have individual blocks i could call with an `\def\Block{i} \input{Maingraph}`. Then place each block in a figure (centered) in an `article` or `book`. Which is solution 2.

MWE below

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\def\Couleur{blue}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
fleche/.style={->,>=latex,very thick, color=\Couleur!30!white},
mkt/.style={anchor=south ,minimum width=100pt,minimum height=25pt},
logo/.style={anchor=south},
noeud/.style={minimum width=80pt,minimum height=20pt},
central/.style={minimum width=50pt,minimum height=20pt},
bro/.style={font=\tiny,minimum width=40pt,  minimum height=10pt},
background/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=0.2cm,rounded corners=5mm,opacity=0.7,fill=#1!30},
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[   matrix of nodes,
      row sep = 0.5cm,
      column sep = 0.6cm,
      every node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,text centered,draw=\Couleur!50},
      row 1/.style={nodes={mkt}},
      row 2/.style={nodes={bro}},
      row 3/.style={nodes={central}},
      row 4/.style={nodes={noeud}},
      row 5/.style={nodes={bro}},
    ]
\matrix (orga) 
{       1-1         &           &   1-3             &           \\  %[1cm] %level 1
        2-1     &           &   2-3     &           \\  %level 2
                    & 3-2   &                       &           \\  %level 3
        4-1     &           &   4-3             &           \\ [-0.2cm] %level 4
};

%------------------ Flèches -------------------------
% Left
    \draw[fleche] (orga-1-1) - - (orga-2-1) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-1) - - (orga-4-1) ;

% Right
    \draw[fleche] (orga-1-3) - - (orga-2-3) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-3) - - (orga-4-3) ;

% South
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-3) - - (orga-4-1) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-1.south east) - - (orga-4-3.south west) ;

% From South
%Gauche
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north west) - - (orga-1-1.south east);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-1.south east) - - (orga-3-2.north west) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-1.north east) - - (orga-3-2.south west) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south west) - - (orga-4-1.north east);
%Droit
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north east) - - (orga-1-3.south west);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-3.south west) - - (orga-3-2.north east) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-3.north west) - - (orga-3-2.south east) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south east) - - (orga-4-3.north west);


   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%        \node [background={red},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-4-1),
%                    label=above:{Case 1}] {};
%        \node [background={blue},
%                    fit=(orga-1-3) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=above:{Case 2}] {};
%        \node [background={green},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-1-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 3}] {};
%        \node [background={orange},
%                    fit=(orga-4-1) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 4}] {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you using a beamer presentation or is this going to be standalone only (i.e. also no standalone frame)? If it is a beamer presentation, then you only need the `beamer-overlay-styles` library, same applies to the standalone frame.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat in beamer I was thinking of the "visible" on style. But I'd like to have independent standalone indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a poor-cat's version of the nice `visible on` style that ships with the `beamer-overlay-styles` library. You can assign each element a class, which controls its visibility. So `class={1,3}` means that the element shows up on the first and third overlay. If you do a beamer presentation, you can load the `beamer-overlay-styles` library, and forget about all this `class` stuff and use `visible on=<1,3>` instead. However, you may still be interested in the `recycle bounding box` style in case that you not only change the visibility but have different elements on different slides, as it happens with `\pause` and `\ifnum`s.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
%membership test    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{memberQ}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{0}%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i#1\pgfmath@token@stop
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup}
\def\pgfmath@member@i#1{%
    \ifx\pgfmath@token@stop#1%
    \else
      \edef\pgfutil@tmpc{#1}%
      \ifx\pgfutil@tmpc\pgfutil@tmpa\relax%
      \gdef\pgfutil@tmpb{1}%
      \fi%
      \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i
    \fi}  
\tikzset{recycle bounding box/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figbb@#1{%
(\the\pgf@picminx,\the\pgf@picminy) rectangle (\the\pgf@picmaxx,\the\pgf@picmaxy)}\relax}},
execute at begin picture={%
\ifcsname figbb@#1\endcsname
 \edef\figbb{\csname figbb@#1\endcsname}
 \path \figbb;
\fi}}}  
\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\def\Couleur{blue}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
fleche/.style={->,>=latex,very thick, color=\Couleur!30!white},
mkt/.style={anchor=south ,minimum width=100pt,minimum height=25pt},
logo/.style={anchor=south},
noeud/.style={minimum width=80pt,minimum height=20pt},
central/.style={minimum width=50pt,minimum height=20pt},
bro/.style={font=\tiny,minimum width=40pt,  minimum height=10pt},
background/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=0.2cm,rounded corners=5mm,opacity=0.7,fill=#1!30},
class/.code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro\itest{memberQ("{#1}",\X)||(\X==5)}%
      \ifnum\itest=1
       \tikzset{opacity=1}
      \else
       \tikzset{opacity=0}
      \fi
      }}

\foreach \X in {1,...,5} {%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[recycle bounding box=A] %if you have size-changing animations
\matrix[matrix of nodes,
      row sep = 0.5cm,
      column sep = 0.6cm,
      every node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,text centered,draw=\Couleur!50},
      row 1/.style={nodes={mkt}},
      row 2/.style={nodes={bro}},
      row 3/.style={nodes={central}},
      row 4/.style={nodes={noeud}},
      row 5/.style={nodes={bro}},
      ampersand replacement=\&] (orga) 
{       |[class={1,3}]| 1-1         \&           \&  |[class={2,3}]| 1-3             \&           \\  %[1cm] %level 1
        |[class={1}]| 2-1     \&           \& |[class={2}]|  2-3     \&           \\  %level 2
                    \& |[class={5}]| 3-2   \&                       \&           \\  %level 3
        |[class={1,4}]| 4-1     \&           \& |[class={2,4}]|  4-3             \&           \\ [-0.2cm] %level 4
};

%------------------ Flèches -------------------------
% Left
    \draw[fleche,class={1}] (orga-1-1) -- (orga-2-1) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={1}] (orga-2-1) -- (orga-4-1) ;

% Right
    \draw[fleche,class={2}] (orga-1-3) -- (orga-2-3) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={2}] (orga-2-3) -- (orga-4-3) ;

% South
    \draw[fleche,class={4}] (orga-4-3) -- (orga-4-1) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={4}] (orga-4-1.south east) - - (orga-4-3.south west) ;

% From South
%Gauche
\ifnum\X=5
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north west) - - (orga-1-1.south east);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-1.south east) - - (orga-3-2.north west) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-1.north east) - - (orga-3-2.south west) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south west) - - (orga-4-1.north east);
%Droit
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north east) - - (orga-1-3.south west);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-3.south west) - - (orga-3-2.north east) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-3.north west) - - (orga-3-2.south east) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south east) - - (orga-4-3.north west);


%    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%        \node [background={red},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-4-1),
%                    label=above:{Case 1}] {};
%        \node [background={blue},
%                    fit=(orga-1-3) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=above:{Case 2}] {};
%        \node [background={green},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-1-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 3}] {};
%        \node [background={orange},
%                    fit=(orga-4-1) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 4}] {};
%     \end{pgfonlayer}
\fi

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A slight modification allows you to shrink the "overlays" to their respective size: draw things in the overlay mode and only select the bounding box to include things that you really want.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
%membership test    
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{memberQ}{2}{%
  \begingroup%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpb{0}%
    \edef\pgfutil@tmpa{#2}%
    \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i#1\pgfmath@token@stop
    \edef\pgfmathresult{\pgfutil@tmpb}%
    \pgfmath@smuggleone\pgfmathresult%
  \endgroup}
\def\pgfmath@member@i#1{%
    \ifx\pgfmath@token@stop#1%
    \else
      \edef\pgfutil@tmpc{#1}%
      \ifx\pgfutil@tmpc\pgfutil@tmpa\relax%
      \gdef\pgfutil@tmpb{1}%
      \fi%
      \expandafter\pgfmath@member@i
    \fi}  
\tikzset{recycle bounding box/.style={%
execute at end picture={%
\immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\figbb@#1{%
(\the\pgf@picminx,\the\pgf@picminy) rectangle (\the\pgf@picmaxx,\the\pgf@picmaxy)}\relax}},
execute at begin picture={%
\ifcsname figbb@#1\endcsname
 \edef\figbb{\csname figbb@#1\endcsname}
 \path \figbb;
\fi}}}  
\tikzset{ 
reuse path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}} 
} 

\makeatother
\usetikzlibrary{
    backgrounds,
    fit,
    matrix,
    positioning,
}

\def\Couleur{blue}

\begin{document}


\tikzset{
fleche/.style={->,>=latex,very thick, color=\Couleur!30!white},
mkt/.style={anchor=south ,minimum width=100pt,minimum height=25pt},
logo/.style={anchor=south},
noeud/.style={minimum width=80pt,minimum height=20pt},
central/.style={minimum width=50pt,minimum height=20pt},
bro/.style={font=\tiny,minimum width=40pt,  minimum height=10pt},
background/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=0.2cm,rounded corners=5mm,opacity=0.7,fill=#1!30},
class/.code={\pgfmathtruncatemacro\itest{memberQ("{#1}",\X)||(\X==5)}%
      \ifnum\itest=1
       \tikzset{opacity=1,overlay=false}
      \else
       \tikzset{opacity=0,overlay=true}
      \fi
      }}

\foreach \X in {1,...,5} {%
\begin{tikzpicture}%[recycle bounding box=A] %if you have size-changing animations
\matrix[matrix of nodes,overlay,
      row sep = 0.5cm,
      column sep = 0.6cm,
      every node/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,text centered,draw=\Couleur!50},
      row 1/.style={nodes={mkt}},
      row 2/.style={nodes={bro}},
      row 3/.style={nodes={central}},
      row 4/.style={nodes={noeud}},
      row 5/.style={nodes={bro}},
      ampersand replacement=\&] (orga) 
{       |[class={1,3}]| 1-1         \& |[class={3},noeud,opacity=0]| 2-3         \&  |[class={2,3}]| 1-3\\  %[1cm] %level 1
        |[class={1}]| 2-1     \&           \& |[class={2}]|  2-3\\  %level 2
                    \& |[class={5}]| 3-2   \&                      \\  %level 3
        |[class={1,4}]| 4-1     \&  |[class={4},noeud,opacity=0]| 2-3         \& |[class={2,4}]|  4-3\\[-0.2cm] %level 4
};

%------------------ Flèches -------------------------
% Left
    \draw[fleche,class={1}] (orga-1-1) -- (orga-2-1) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={1}] (orga-2-1) -- (orga-4-1) ;

% Right
    \draw[fleche,class={2}] (orga-1-3) -- (orga-2-3) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={2}] (orga-2-3) -- (orga-4-3) ;

% South
    \draw[fleche,class={4}] (orga-4-3) -- (orga-4-1) ;
    \draw[fleche,class={4}] (orga-4-1.south east) - - (orga-4-3.south west) ;

% From South
%Gauche
\ifnum\X=5
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north west) - - (orga-1-1.south east);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-1.south east) - - (orga-3-2.north west) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-1.north east) - - (orga-3-2.south west) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south west) - - (orga-4-1.north east);
%Droit
    %Up
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.north east) - - (orga-1-3.south west);
    %Center
    \draw[fleche] (orga-2-3.south west) - - (orga-3-2.north east) ;
    %Down
    \draw[fleche] (orga-4-3.north west) - - (orga-3-2.south east) ;
    \draw[fleche] (orga-3-2.south east) - - (orga-4-3.north west);


%    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%        \node [background={red},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-4-1),
%                    label=above:{Case 1}] {};
%        \node [background={blue},
%                    fit=(orga-1-3) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=above:{Case 2}] {};
%        \node [background={green},
%                    fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-1-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 3}] {};
%        \node [background={orange},
%                    fit=(orga-4-1) (orga-4-3),
%                    label=right:{Case 4}] {};
%     \end{pgfonlayer}
\fi
\begin{scope}[overlay]
\node[fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-4-1)] (F1){};
\node[fit=(orga-1-3) (orga-4-3)] (F2){};
\node[fit=(orga-1-1) (orga-1-3)] (F3){};
\node[fit=(orga-4-1) (orga-4-3)] (F4){};
\end{scope}
\ifnum\X<5
\path[use as bounding box] (F\X.south west) rectangle (F\X.north east);
\else
\path[use as bounding box] (orga.south west) rectangle (orga.north east);
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're a lion!  merci :) 
Just to give some context and probably have a better view on what I should do ... I have 15 chapters in `book` that turns into 15 lectures when I use `beamer`. Each chapter/lecture has a "reference graph" (as the one above) that I decline along sections to have a final visual that corresponds to the chapter. So on section 1, I use a `\def\X{1} \input{CatsGraph.tex}` to include the first block of your graph..
I have the shadow (as loads of white space) of what's not displayed on the graph. Am I using the right method ? (since the figure placing will be off in `book`)

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Thanks for the explanations, IMHO this makes the question very different from what is written above, at least from how I interpret it. I will leave the answer for others, it may still be useful for some.

Comment: Understood Mr cat. Thanks again, your answers help me move forward with tricky TikZ.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Thanks! There is no need to accept an answer that does not solve the question. I had just solved a different problem. I do believe that it should be possible to achieve what you want, but obviously in a matrix (or in any framework that uses relative positioning) this is a bit more tricky. However, you get *almost* what you want if you replace `\tikzset{opacity=0}` by `\tikzset{opacity=0,overlay}` in the `class` code.

Comment: I'll try hacking the class then;) It is actually my first try with matrices of nodes. I initially built these graphs with loads of `below=` and `above=` whereas i had in reality that type of matrix shape. I thought it would be a good exercise to try another method. But totally agreed, by nature, the matrix object is more difficult to cut.

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb I added a version that fixes the bounding boxes as you describe,

Comment: @schrodingerscat and once again, you found a solution before I even had time to make an edit !!!! :)

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Being a cat helps.

Comment: @ Schrödinger'scat ahaha I once thought you used to be a marmot...

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb That's a very timely thought: https://marmots.org/the-marmot-emerge/

Comment: mmmm mmmm... I might be so wrong but I recognized a style... anyhow. A demain for other questions :)

Comment: @schrodingerscat I am still digesting your smart code. `1-1`-`1-3` or `4-1`-`4-3` distance shrinks when used as an individual part. Playing with the different options I did not manage to keep the original (as in the main diagram) distance. May I ask you where shall I look to solve that?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Can you please try to explain a bit better what you mean by "distance shrinks when used as an individual part"? What does "individual" mean? This was all written some time back and I forget the details. (I'll plan to look at it in a couple of hours.)

Comment: @schrodingers of course ! In your second answer, I compare the last image (the full diagram) vs the "individual" (sub diagrams). 
On the full diagram, `1-1` and `1-3` are quite distant whereas on the sub diagram representing only `1-1` and `1-3`, they are much closer. It's the case for other horizontal or vertical subdiagrams. 
I imagine creating the subdiagrams ignores nodes not necessary to draw this subdiagram and dsitance get reduced. 
Is there a simple way to keep the distancing ?

Comment: @Julien-ElieTaieb Yes, you have a good point! If nodes are in the `overlay` mode, they do not contribute to the width of the matrix. So unfortunately at this point the only possibility that came to my mind is to add dummy nodes that restore the distances.

Comment: Merci ! it does perfectly the job.