# addding to tikz picture sequentially in article

Tags: tikz-pgf, article

Is it possible to add paths to a tikz picture sequentially in an article? 
something like onslide in a beamer setting but in article class without redrawing the whole picture

Comment: Yes, it is. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542668/194703.

Comment: why when I changed the standalone to article it does not work?It only compiles the first object

Comment: It does work. Maybe you forgot `\usepackage{tikz}`?

Comment: no I did not I have\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}. and it does not output any errors.

Comment: foreach is not working but when I use \def\X{#} it does work for that number. THANK YOU! that is great