# Spy magnifier shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

I'm trying to zoom in a tikzpicture with the **Spy library** but I would like the shape of the *magnifier* to be given by a path (for example, a hexagon shape). Is it possible? And is it possible to show **only** the zoomed portion?

Here is a MWE taken for the pgfmanual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.fractals,spy}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[spy using overlays={size=12mm}]
\draw [decoration=Koch snowflake]
decorate { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
\spy [blue,magnification=5] on (1,0.5) in node at (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the polygon node shape from the TikZ `shapes` library like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.fractals,spy, shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, spy using overlays={size=12mm}]
\draw [decoration=Koch snowflake]
decorate { decorate{ decorate{ decorate{ (0,0) -- (2,0) }}}};
\spy [blue,magnification=5] on (1,0.5) in node at (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Hexagon spy shape]

Comment: Thanks but how can a path be explicitly defined? Like e.g. `\path (1,1)--(0.5,0.5)--(1.5,0.5)--cycle`

Comment: And how can the magnified part be the only part showing (hidding the original picture)?

Comment: For a custom node shape see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294876/pgf-tikz-node-custom-shape. If you do not want the original picture, then why draw it and then use spy - just draw only the large version. To help you further, you need to edit your question, and include a picture of what you seek and describe what is causing you problems.

Comment: The problem is the `\clip` is not working here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/550140/zoom-in-a-tikz-mindmap. That is why I am trying with `\spy` that works.

Comment: I fail to understand how `clip` fails to clip. I do not think you need or want `spy` for this purpose. Include a picture of what you seek and describe what is causing you problems.

Comment: everything is explained in the link above with images and code. The `\clip` (in the beginning of the code) clips but some path joints are not clipped. Strange behaviour. But executing `\spy` at the end of the code works perfectly. Can you please take a look at the link with my mindmap question?